# "up to" vs. "in excess of"

Tags: british-english

When you say "teams in excess of" or else "teams/crews up to", do you mean the number of teams included or totality of people involved?

I have seen different use of the expression which made it confusing for me.

Lets say one supervises 5 teams which amounts to total 200 people. What is the best form of using these phrases in this context?

Is the word "teams" here corresponds to people involved or number of teams

Comment: I'm not sure of your question.  The two phrases you mention are deliberately ambiguous -- they suggest a range of values.  If you want to say the exact number, you use the exact number.

Answer (score 3):

> *Teams in excess of 40*

This means teams of size 41 or greater.

> *Teams up to 40.*

This means teams of size 40 or smaller.

---

If teams may consist of no more than 40 people, the rules might say:

> "Teams can have up to 40 members."

or:

> "Team cannot be in excess of 40 members."

Either wording would allow a team to have 38, 39, or 40 members, but not 41.